# How to change price of an In App Purchase Subscription in AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to change a price of a auto-renewable subscription in iTunes Connect but I can't find any option to do so. How can I change the price? The price is already setup and I can just set up an introductory price. The app is not released yet and I don't want to delete the IAP because I would loose my localisation.

[image: iTunes Connect Subscription Pricing Pane]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Select the product and under Subscription Prices tap on View all Subscription Pricing.

[image]

In the Subscription Prices tab of the new screen select Starting Price below the Current Prices title:

[image]

And then Edit Price Change in the new screen that appears:

[image]

Finally select Recalculate prices for all territories and follow the instructions:

[image]

Comment: It worked for me :D. There is a heads-up: Apple updated my subscription price in the date I chose, but in the UTC timezone. I had some problem with a few users because it was hours earlier than we expected and we were running a marketing campaign saying "last day with a low price"

Comment: @RobertGummesson see my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

**Update for people using the newer portal (aug 2020)**

It seems like you can now only update the price at the earliest, starting the next day.

1. Click on "Manage" under In-App Purchases in the left sidebar

[image]

2. Click on the subscription from your group you want to change the price for.

[image]

3. Then click on the plus on the right "Subscription Prices" and select "Plan Subscription Price Change"

[image]

4. Select all your regions and click next

[image]

5. Select the start data (earliest tomorrow) and the new price

[image]

6. Double check the new prices for all regions and click next

[image]

7. Then agree to the price change and click done

[image]

8. Lastly, very important, don't forget to click "Save" in the top right. Since you won't get any pop-up about disregarding the changes you have made. I for one, forgot this and a few days later realised that some price changes did not happen.

[image]

Comment: Still, they showing in the upcoming list with today's date. why?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, the updated approach to change prices for subscriptions can be found here https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc9870599e

Answer (score 0):

To set the price for a subscription, make sure that you are logged in with a role as the Account Holder, Admin, or App Manager, NOT as something else like a sandbox user.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Click on the **plus icon** then Step 2 **Choose Date** then
**Change Price** Then choose the **effective users.** Click Next and enjoy.

[image: screnhsot]

Answer (score -1):

In iTunes Connect,

_ Select your app

_ Go to features

_ In-App Purchases.

Select the subscription you want to update.

Go to Subscription Prices section:

[image]

Click on + icon and follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks your answer but that does not work. I can't change the price there. I can just set up an introductory price. The app is not released yet but I have set up a price. I just want to change it.

Comment: You should inform it in your question. So you can't. You have to delete and recreate the IAP.