# Submit app to App Store after testing on Test Flight

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, itunes-app

I have submitted an update to an app and tested it using Testflight.

How do I submit it to app store in the future?

As per https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7cbda8c55, the "iOS app" version that should appear on the left is showing up but a version that is old. How do I set the pricing, etc. and submit the latest to the store?

Thanks and Best Regards

Mrinmay

Comment: Can someone please answer this question? I am in the exact same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new version on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com, click on your app and than click the plus button which is on the lower part of the left menu it says “version or platform” see the green arrow on image [image: check the green arrow]

You can change the pricing while updating or at any time see here for more details: [How to change price of an In App Purchase Subscription in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390113/how-to-change-price-of-an-in-app-purchase-subscription-in-itunes-connect)