# apple In-App Purchases Subscription products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

i create apple In-App Purchases Subscription products and didn't deploy it yet and i want to change its prices before deploy but can't find any way to change it unless delete every product and recreate it again

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596038/1128713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from app store connect, goto manage In-App Purchases Subscription and then chose the item you want to change its prices, and press on `Plan a Price Change`

[image]